# Rest in Spring Web project

Tags: spring

I am writing a web project in spring 3.1.0.

How can I link the interface and the class so that i inject Initialized interface to @Controller ?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you look at some tutorials like [this one](http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions - How to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use context:annotation-driven and @Autowired annotation for this . Check the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).